# How to float text around a tikz picture in a LaTeX theorem environment?

Tags: latex, tikz

I don't like to use an outer picture editor just like xfig, because it don't make work. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cutwin}

\newtheorem{thm}{tétel}

\begin{document}
    \section{Téglalap}
        \begin{thm}
            A téglalap a területét az oldalhosszakból az
            $$A=ab$$
            képlettel számolhatjuk ki.
        \end{thm}
        \begin{proof}
            A bizonyítás grafikusan igen jól szemléltethető. Vegyünk fel ugyanis egy $a+b$ oldalhosszúságú négyzetet, és ebben helyezzük el a négy egybevágó téglalapot.
            \opencutleft\begin{cutout}{3}{0pt}{\textwidth}{1}
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (3,1) -- (3,0) -- cycle;
                    \draw (3,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,3) -- (3,3) -- cycle;
                    \draw (4,3) -- (4,4) -- (1,4) -- (1,3) -- cycle;
                    \draw (0,4) -- (1,4) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{cutout}
            A nagy négyzet területe $A=(a+b)^2$, a belső kis négyzet oldalhossza $a-b$, így a területe $A'=(a-b)^2$. A kettő különbsége lesz a négy téglalap területének összege:
            \begin{align*}
                (a+b)^2-(a-b)^2&=a^2+b^2+2ab-(a^2+b^2-2ab)=\\
                &=4ab=4A.
            \end{align*}

            Innen egy téglalap területe az egybevágóság miatt már megkapható, és ez pont a tétel állítása.
        \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the picture slips over the upper text, and the space above is empty, the begins the following text. When I alter the spaces, the picture goes evrywhere, and lowering those numbers it's getting closer the planned place, with awaiting it at the number 0. But when I write zero, the translator throws errors because of it and outs. The exact message says "Missing number, treated az zero".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wrapfig` package does not to help inside `proof` environment, so I'll post a very simple *no-float* alternative to the good answer by @dfri.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{cutwin}

\newtheorem{thm}{tétel}

\begin{document}
    \section{Téglalap}
    \begin{thm}
        A téglalap a területét az oldalhosszakból az
        $$A=ab$$
        képlettel számolhatjuk ki.
    \end{thm}
    \begin{proof}
        A bizonyítás grafikusan igen jól szemléltethető. Vegyünk fel ugyanis egy $a+b$ oldalhosszúságú négyzetet, és ebben helyezzük el a négy egybevágó téglalapot.
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (3,1) -- (3,0) -- cycle;
            \draw (3,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,3) -- (3,3) -- cycle;
            \draw (4,3) -- (4,4) -- (1,4) -- (1,3) -- cycle;
            \draw (0,4) -- (1,4) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
        A nagy négyzet területe $A=(a+b)^2$, a belső kis négyzet oldalhossza $a-b$, így a területe $A'=(a-b)^2$. A kettő különbsége lesz a négy téglalap területének összege:
        \begin{align*}
            (a+b)^2-(a-b)^2&=a^2+b^2+2ab-(a^2+b^2-2ab)=\\
            &=4ab=4A.
        \end{align*}

        Innen egy téglalap területe az egybevágóság miatt már megkapható, és ez pont a tétel állítása.
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

outputs:

[image: screenshot]

Notice that I only edited lines 25 and 32 (and commented `\usepackage{cutwin}` in line 12): `center` environment behaves properly also with text of arbitrary length before `\section{}`.

I'll post an update if I work out some good setting for `cutout` environment, which is meant to be used [in theorem-like environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74635/wrapfigure-in-theorem-like-environment/74702#74702).

Answer (score 2):

You're probably best off letting your tikz picture be a part of a figure, to which you can reference from your theorem. One way to achieve this is to embed your tikz picture within a savebox, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

%% Define savebox and tikz picture
\newsavebox{\mytikzpic}
\begin{lrbox}{\mytikzpic} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (3,1) -- (3,0) -- cycle;
        \draw (3,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,3) -- (3,3) -- cycle;
        \draw (4,3) -- (4,4) -- (1,4) -- (1,3) -- cycle;
        \draw (0,4) -- (1,4) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{lrbox} 

\begin{document}
\subsection*{My TiKZ picture within a savebox}
\noindent See my TiKZ picture in Figure~\ref{fig1}.
\begin{theorem}
    I have some theorem using this TiKZ picture in Figure~\ref{fig1}, which yields
    \begin{align*}
        x = c^2 + \sum_{i=1}^4 ab,
     \end{align*}
     \noindent where $a$ and $b$ are side lengths of the rectangles in Figure~\ref{fig1}, and $c$ the side length of the middle square.
     %% Include savebox in a figure
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering 
    \usebox{\mytikzpic} 
    \caption{My TiKZ picture.} 
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}  
     % 

     \noindent And with this, the area has been blahablasized.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Producing the following output:

[image]

Naturally you can move the figure outside of the theorem environment, if you so wish.

---

Note also that if you wish to remove the whole figure caption, just enter the figure as

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering 
    \usebox{\mytikzpic}
\end{figure}
```

In your .tex file, instead producing the following:

[image]